# ActiveAdmin Error: no superclass method `buttons'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm starting with Rails (and I'm also new with Ruby -coming from Python-) and I'm currentrly trying to setup ActiveAdmin for Rails 3.2.3 (Ruby 1.9.3).
I'm following [this guide](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) but I was not able to run it properly. When I run the `rails s` command visiting `localhost:3000/admin` I get

```
NoMethodError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new

Showing /home/lex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activeadmin-0.4.3/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:

super: no superclass method `buttons' for #<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0xb429ae0>
```

I could not find anything useful on Google, what's wrong here?

If you need more info about this exception please tell me.

```
Extracted source (around line #11):

8:       f.input :password
9:       f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :if =>  false  #devise_mapping.rememberable? }
10:     end
11:     f.buttons do
12:       f.commit_button "Login"
13:     end
14:   end
```

Comment: Please post your view code so we can see the line that's generating the exception.

Comment: I've added the source that's raising this exception. BTW there's no custom code, this is the default installation. As you may notice the exception is raised using the built-in ActiveAdmin's devise view. It seems there's nothing such devise:views to extract custom views (but instead they promote the DSL to customize the interface)

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue? I am getting the same problem

Comment: I used @landox solution and ran `bundle update formtastic` and this fixed my issue

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## **For Rails 4+**

If you are running Rails 4+ use `f.actions` instead of `f.buttons`. Here's an issue that talks about this change on the ActiveAdmin repo https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1085

## **Original answer for OP question in 2012**

seems like formtastic 2.2.0 (released today) breaks active_admin and since active_admin requires formtastic >= 2.0.0... put in your Gemfile this

```
gem "formtastic", "~> 2.1.1"
gem "activeadmin", "~> 0.4.3"
```

then run

```
bundle update formtastic
```

then restart your server (if you have it running)..

and should work ok...

Comment: Once you do this, make sure to run `bundle update formtastic`. This will force your application to use the version you specified

Comment: This answer no longer works with newer rails.  Just use `f.actions` instead of `f.buttons` to fix your form.

Answer (score 18):

I had same problem and it's killed my about hours.

I am using rails 4 and active admin form master git:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

I just used "f.actions" instead of "f.buttons"

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "Enter Todo details" do
    f.input :quote_id, :as => :select, :collection => Quote.all.map {|q| [ q.contact,q.id]}, :include_blank => false 
    f.input :name, :label => "Name of customer"
    f.input :state, :as => :select, :collection => ['Active','Closed'], :include_blank => false
    f.input :moving_date
    f.input :revisit
    f.input :address
    f.input :status
  end
  f.actions
end
```

It's works for me.

Comment: I was using Rails 4 and master branch, and this worked and absolute treat for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks for the answer - perfect for rails 4!

Comment: For me this is much better answer as using older version of formtastic

Comment: the accepted answer is from 2012, you need to check the dates before commenting :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it actually fixes the problem + formtastic gem version hacks no longer work with newer Rails.

Answer (score 1):

I have done  following changes in the gemfile

gem 'activeadmin', '0.4.2'
gem 'formtastic', '2.0.0'

and it solved the same issue.reason is same as explained above .the formtastic 2.2.0 is incompatible with activeadmin current version

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions above, but the same error kept popping up. It resolved itself after I closed and reopened `rails server`, but just a note to anyone else that has this problem; make sure you restart the server. :)

Comment: yeah totally.. when you install a new gem you have to restart the server.. ill add this to the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the 'bundle' command to fetch the necessary gems and dependancies (ActiveAdmin, Formtastic, etc.)?
It's a common mistake when starting rails.

Comment: Sure, I did. It installed all dependencies including `formtastic (2.2.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I inherited a project written around July 2012 that uses ActiveAdmin 0.4.0 and `formtastic-bootstrap` (off Git).

Due to URL-generating bugs in that version of AA I upgraded to 0.5.0, but now I get the superclass error.  Anyone know what I should do about this line:

```
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap',   :git => "git://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap.git", :branch => "bootstrap-2"
```